# Get member name that's passed into an Expression

Tags: c#, expression, func

In my `ToString()` override I'm doing something along the lines of:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = "value1";
    public string Prop2 { get; set; } = "value2";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var parts = new[]
        {
            $"{nameof(Prop1)}={Prop1}",
            $"{nameof(Prop2)}={Prop2}",
        };
        return string.Join(",", parts);
    }
}
```

Rather than repeating the same "name=value" operation over and over, is it possible to have a function that can work out the name (e.g. `Prop1`) and the value of that prop?

For example, can I do something like this:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    var parts = new[]
    {
        GetProp(x => x.Prop1), // returns "Prop1=value1"
        GetProp(x => x.Prop2), // returns "Prop2=value2"
        // ...
    };
    return string.Join(",", parts);
}
```

I'm thinking I need a function along the lines of this, but I'm not sure of the implementation to get the members name:

```cs
private string GetProp(Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> exp)
{
    var name = ""; // <---- How to get the name?
    var value = exp.Compile().Invoke(this);
    return $"{name}={value}";
}
```

If I inspect `exp` I can see that the member name is indeed stored under `exp.Body.Member.Name`, but I cant figure out how to access this.

[image]

Comment: Are you set on using Expressions? I ask because this would still require you to manually add a call to GetProp every time you introduce a new property in the class. You could accomplish the same functionality using Reflection but with the added benefit of not having to manually update the method for every new property.

Comment: @estebro It's more for learning, to be honest. I'm quite familiar with Reflection and know how to achieve this functionality using it. I started going down the Expression route and wanted to continue just to see how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to cast the body to a `MemberExpression` like the below :

```
    private string GetProp(Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> exp)
    {
            var name = ""; // <---- How to get the name?
            if (exp.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
            {
                name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
            else if (exp.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression && unaryExpression.Operand is MemberExpression unaryMemberExpression)
            {
                name = unaryMemberExpression.Member.Name;
            }

            var value = exp.Compile().Invoke(this);
            return $"{name}={value}";
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xAhNrl)

**Edit:** UnaryExpression checking added.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly thought I had already tried this and the cast returned null, but I must be mistaken. This does exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of any reason why this would work in some cases but not others? I created a MRP to debug this, and it works as expected in there. However when I implement the exact same function and call it in the exact same way in my actual project, `exp.Body is MemberExpression` is false. I cant figure out what's different that would cause this different behaviour

Comment: This is the [code in question](https://github.com/devklick/Snek/blob/0e5354a5a1ce5bd7efd09e17efc6fb4e5bd774cb/Snek/Settings/GameSettings.cs#L55)

Comment: @devklick try to log the Body's type when it fails

Comment: Turns out when trying to do `GetProp(x => x.SomeInt)` with an integer property, the expression body is a `UnaryExpression` rather than a `MemberExpression`. In which case, I can cast to a `UnaryExpression` then cast it's `Operand` property to a `MemberExpression` and get the property name from there.

Comment: @devklick feel free to edit the answer or I will update it when I have time.